# How to create a snapshot in Nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I need to backup my indexes from elasticsearch, and then restore it. I can't find an example. I tried to write something like this:

```
public virtual ISnapshotResponse BackUp()
{
    return _client.Snapshot("D:\\snapshots", "1", descriptor => descriptor
        .Indices(_indexString)
        .IncludeGlobalState(false));
}
```

But it has invalid response because of `repository`parameter.

Please, help me to create a snapshot and then restore my indexes.

Comment: You need to register a snapshot repository with Elasticsearch first before you can take a snapshot. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html.

Answer (score 0):

Step: 1

**Sense:**
e.g.

```
PUT /_snapshot/es_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
   "settings": {
        "location": "C:/SIEM/New/elasticsearch-5.4.3/es_backup",
        "compress": true
    }
}
```

---

Step: 2

ES `Configuration elasticsearch.ym`l file set the backup path:
e.g.

```
path.repo: ["C:/SIEM/New/elasticsearch-5.4.3/es_backup"]
```

---

Step: 3

C# :
e.g.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
                var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri);
                var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

                var result = client.Snapshot("es_backup", "snapshot_4", x => x.WaitForCompletion(true));
```